# Python -check if a key:value pair exists at least once in a nested json object

Tags: python, json

I've got a JSON-object looking like this:
[image]

I want to check if one of the given prices ({0} , {1} , {2}) contains **priceType == "04" and countriesIncluded == "DE"**

My code:

```
r = requests.get(f'https://api.vlb.de/api/v2/product/{isbn}/ean?access_token=9xx9xxxxxc9')
        vlb = json.loads(r.text)
        for i in vlb['prices']:
            if i['priceType'] == "04" and i["countriesIncluded"] == "DE":
                neupreis = i['priceAmount']
            else:
                neupreis = "False"
```

The problem with my attempt is the following: *neupreis* will always get the value of the last price (in this case {2} where the condition is false) but I want to check if any of the prices meet the condition.

Is there a better way to search through a JSON object than the *for-loop* I'm using?

PS: I've found some similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none of those Json-objects were as nested as mine… Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code, if I understand you correctly, you could just do something like this:

```py
r = requests.get(f'https://api.vlb.de/api/v2/product/{isbn}/ean?access_token=9xx9xxxxxc9')
vlb = json.loads(r.text)

neupreis = "False"
for i in vlb['prices']:
    if i['priceType'] == "04" and i["countriesIncluded"] == "DE":
        neupreis = i['priceAmount']
        break
```

A different approach would be to use a list-comprehension like this:

```
neupreise = [i['priceAmount'] for i in vlb["prices"] if i['priceType'] == "04" and i["countriesIncluded"] == "DE"]
```

In this case all the `priceAmounts` for the prices that meet the criterium are saved in a list. If the list is empty, then none of them met the criterium.

Comment: you should include a break statement once the correct value is found.  Also your indentation is way off.

Comment: This will only give you the last matching one, what if you have multiple ones which matches the condition

Comment: @jack the question was about if **any** of the prices meet the condition. This is what the code does. Otherwise you could append it to a list or better yet directly use a list-comprehension.

Comment: Awesome,that solved my problem and I just had to change 1-2 lines of code, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should help if you want to check if you don't want the last forloop to silently do nothing you can add before the second loop `if indexes:`

```
r = requests.get(f'https://api.vlb.de/api/v2/product/{isbn}/ean?access_token=9xx9xxxxxc9')
    vlb = json.loads(r.text)
    indexes=[]
        for i, preisDict in enumerate(vlb['prices']):
            if preisDict['priceType'] == "04" and preisDict["countriesIncluded"] == "DE":
                #neupreis = preisDict['priceAmount']
                indexes.append(i)
# Now you can access the Prices which meets the condition using
for i in indexes: # Will silently do nothing if the is not any which matches the condition
    vlb['prices'][i] # then do something with the right pricetypes
```